# Expressjs How to enable CORS on just one route?

Tags: node.js, express

The code below does not work

```
app.post('/blah', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD');
    res.status(204).send();
});
```

Note that I don't want turn on CORS for the whole app.

Comment: What is the exact CORS request you are sending from the client?  It may also require support of the OPTIONS request if the client decides to do pre-flighting.

Comment: @jfriend00 Your're right. I added app.options for this url and it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as an answer since it turned out to be the issue (per my earlier comment).  Depending upon the exact CORS request you are making, then browser may decide that it needs to do a pre-flight of the request.   If it does, then you also need to set the custom headers in a matching OPTIONS request.

A number of things can trigger a pre-flight such as custom headers, certain verbs being used, certain auth mechanisms, etc...

There's a description of what types of requests trigger a pre-flight here in these articles:

[Using CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-types-of-cors-requests)

[Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests)

Basically, it's any request that isn't defined as a "simple request" where simple requests only use GET, HEAD and POST and only a small set of custom headers.  Anything else and even some values for certain headers will trigger a preflight request where the browser sends an OPTIONS request to the same URL request pre-flight authorization before sending the actual URL.

Answer (score 7):

you can use something like this :

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var  corsOptions = { origin: 'http://yourapp.com'}
var app = express()

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a Single Route'})
})

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 8080')
})
```

By default, only 6 response headers are exposed over CORS:

1. Cache-Control
2. Content-Language
3. Content-Type
4. Expires
5. Last-Modified
6. Pragma

If you want to expose other headers, you can use the exposedHeaders option:

```
 corsOptions = {
  exposedHeaders: ['Content-Length', 'X-Foo', 'X-Bar'],
}
```

Please refer this for more detail on CORS:

> [More detail on cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: router.post('/get-token', cors(corsOptions), blacklistController.getToken) this does not  work.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Express are you using? v4 of the API exposes a `set()` method on `res` where you can define headers. If passing multiple headers, you pass an object. Try something like this:

```
res.set({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD'
});
```

[Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set).

Answer (score 0):

Building on Clark Jung's reply, you can use https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enable-cors-for-a-single-route

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.get('/products/:id', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a Single Route'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you use https://github.com/expressjs/cors. You can just use like this.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Or refer to here https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
 // Handle the post for this route
});
```

Comment: This did not pay attention to the core part of the question that the OP wants to enable CORS on ONLY one route, not all routes.  You don't answer that at all.

Comment: It actually solves the problem, just not pointed out in the original comment
https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enable-cors-for-a-single-route